# Getting unexpected result when compiling with clang optimization

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, clang

I found a bug in my code that only happens when I enable compiler optimizations -O1 or greater. I traced the bug and it seems that I can't use the boost type_erased adaptor on a boost transformed range when optimizations are enabled. I wrote this c++ program to reproduce it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/type_erased.hpp>

using namespace boost::adaptors;
using namespace std;

int addOne(int b) {
  return b + 1;
}

int main(int, char**) {
  vector<int> nums{ 1, 2, 3 };

  auto result1 = nums | transformed(addOne) | type_erased<int, boost::forward_traversal_tag>();
  auto result2 = nums | transformed(addOne);
  auto result3 = nums | type_erased<int, boost::forward_traversal_tag>();

  for (auto n : result1)
    cout << n << " ";
  cout << endl;

  for (auto n : result2)
    cout << n << " ";
  cout << endl;

  for (auto n : result3)
    cout << n << " ";
  cout << endl;
}
```

When I run this program without any optimizations, I get the following output:

```
2 3 4
2 3 4
1 2 3
```

When I run it with the -O1 flag, I get the following:

```
1 1 1
2 3 4
1 2 3
```

I am using clang++ to compile it. The version of clang that I am using is:

Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)

I don't know if I am doing something wrong, or if it is a boost/clang bug.

**edit:**

Changed it to

```
type_erased<int, boost::forward_traversal_tag, const int>()
```

and it works now. The third template argument is the reference type, setting the reference to const prolongs the timespan of the temporary created by the transformed.

Comment: Removing `type_erased` from the computation of `result1` gives correct result even with optimization.

Comment: Yeah I know that, that would be equivalent to result2 which is correct. But I need the type of result to be type erased. I used result2 and result3 to demonstrate that both adaptors work if not used together.

Comment: I just commented my observation. I have zero knowledge on the range stuff :(. How about using `boost::any_iterator` ?

Comment: That's what I was trying to do and that's how I got to the type_erased adaptor. You can't iterate on one iterator, you need two of them, a begin and end. A range is a pair of iterators (begin and end). The type erasure adaptor (type_erased) should return a boost::any_range, which is a pair of boost::any_iterator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using

```
type_erased<int, boost::forward_traversal_tag, const int>()
```

works. The third template argument is the reference type, setting the reference to const prolongs the timespan of the temporary created by the transformed.

Comment: I have just verified that, indeed, this also silences ubsan/asan as well as valgrind on my system (where indeed using the temp also removed the symptoms). Not tried with clang though.

Answer (score 9):

**EDIT** In fact there's more to this than meets the eye. There is another usability issue, which does address the problem. See [OP's self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40492610/85371)

---

You're falling into the number 1 pitfall with Boost Range v2 (and Boost Proto etc.).

`nums | transformed(addOne)` is a temporary. The `type_erased` adaptor stores ***a reference*** to that.

After assigning the type-erased adaptor to the `resultN` variable, the temporary is destructed.

What you have is a dangling reference :(

This is a highly unintuitive effect, and the number 1 reason why I limit the use of Range V2 in my codebase: I've been there all too often.

Here is a workaround:

```
auto tmp = nums | transformed(addOne);
auto result = tmp | type_erased<int, boost::forward_traversal_tag>();
```

`-fsanitize=address,undefined` confirms that the UB is gone when using the named temporary.

Comment: auto tmp = nums | transformed(addOne);
auto result1 = tmp | type_erased<int, boost::forward_traversal_tag>();

This still outputs 1 1 1.

Comment: What compiler, platform and boost version is that? (Is there a SSCCE to check for ... subtle differences)

Comment: Setting the type_erased reference type to const fixed the issue (see my edit on the question). I am using Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38), on Mac OS Sierra. Boost version 1.62.

Comment: Wow. You can add this as an answer. Somehow I think I now half-remember @_jv finding this earlier and I completely forgot about it. Also don't know why anymore. Did you file an issue with the boost devs?

Comment: @sehe clang 3.8 C++14 and C++1z, Boost 1.62.0 failed with [this test](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/vMBzG5ujyh1lPWHd)

Comment: @sehe I filed a bug to boost although I am not sure if it actually is a bug. https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/12595