# Create library to override operator*() of iterator - risk dangling pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, iterator, adapter

I am trying to create my own [`boost::adaptors::transformed`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/transformed.html).

Here is the related [boost code](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp).

Here is its usage (modified from [a SO answer by LogicStuff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42326273/3577745)):-

```
C funcPointer(B& b){ 
    //"funcPointer" is function convert from "B" to "C"
    return instance-of-C
}

MyArray<B> test;  //<-- any type, must already have begin() & end()

for(C c : test | boost::adaptor::transformed(funcPointer)) {
    //... something ....
}
```

The result will be the same as :-

```
for(auto b : test) {
    C c = funcPointer(b);
    //... something ...
}
```

## My Attempt

I created `CollectAdapter` that aim to work like `boost::adaptor::transformed`.
It works OK in most common cases.

*Here is the full [**demo**](http://ideone.com/zPS9qp) and [**back up**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be5a40567a0088cc).* (same as below code)

The problematic part is `CollectAdapter` - the core of my library.
I don't know whether I should cache the `collection_` **by-pointer** or **by-value**.

**CollectAdapter** encapsulates underlying `collection_` (e.g. pointer to `std::vector<>`) :-

```
template<class COLLECTION,class ADAPTER>class CollectAdapter{
    using CollectAdapterT=CollectAdapter<COLLECTION,ADAPTER>;
    COLLECTION* collection_;    //<---- #1  problem? should cache by value?
    ADAPTER adapter_;           //<---- = func1 (or func2)
    public: CollectAdapter(COLLECTION& collection,ADAPTER adapter){
        collection_=&collection;
        adapter_=adapter;
    }
    public: auto begin(){
        return IteratorAdapter<
            decltype(std::declval<COLLECTION>().begin()),
            decltype(adapter_)>
            (collection_->begin(),adapter_);
    }
    public: auto end(){ ..... }
};
```

**`IteratorAdapter`** (used above) encapsulates underlying iterator, change behavior of `operator*` :-

```
template<class ITERATORT,class ADAPTER>class IteratorAdapter : public ITERATORT {
    ADAPTER adapter_;
    public: IteratorAdapter(ITERATORT underlying,ADAPTER adapter) :
        ITERATORT(underlying),
        adapter_(adapter)
    {   }
    public: auto operator*(){
        return adapter_(ITERATORT::operator*());
    }
};
```

**`CollectAdapterWidget`** (used below) is just a helper class to construct **`CollectAdapter`**-instance.

It can be used like:-

```
int func1(int i){   return i+10;   }
int main(){
    std::vector<int> test; test.push_back(5);
    for(auto b:CollectAdapterWidget::createAdapter(test,func1)){
        //^ create "CollectAdapter<std::vector<int>,func1>" instance
         //here, b=5+10=15
    }
}
```

## Problem

The above code works OK in most cases, except when `COLLECTION` is a temporary object.

More specifically, dangling pointer potentially occurs when I create ***adapter of adapter of adapter ...***.

```
int func1(int i){   return i+10;    }
int func2(int i){   return i+100;   }
template<class T> auto utilityAdapter(const T& t){
    auto adapter1=CollectAdapterWidget::createAdapter(t,func1);
    auto adapter12=CollectAdapterWidget::createAdapter(adapter1,func2);
    //"adapter12.collection_" point to "adapter1"
    return adapter12;
    //end of scope, "adapter1" is deleted
    //"adapter12.collection_" will be dangling pointer
}
int main(){
    std::vector<int> test;
    test.push_back(5);
    for(auto b:utilityAdapter(test)){
        std::cout<< b<<std::endl;   //should 5+10+100 = 115
    }
}
```

This will cause run time error.       Here is [**the dangling-pointer demo**](http://ideone.com/zMXXcu).

In the real usage, if the interface is more awesome, e.g. use `|` operator, the bug will be even harder to be detected :-

```
//inside "utilityAdapter(t)"
return t|func1;        //OK!
return t|func1|func2;  //dangling pointer
```

## Question

How to improve my library to fix this error while keeping **performance** & **robustness** & **maintainablilty** near the same level?

In other words, how to cache data or pointer of `COLLECTION` (that can be **adapter** or **real data-structure**) elegantly?

Alternatively, if it is easier to answer by coding from scratch (than modifying my code), go for it.   :)

## My workarounds

The current code caches **by pointer**.
The main idea of workarounds is to cache **by value** instead.

### Workaround 1 (always "by value")

Let **adapter** cache the **value** of `COLLECTION`.
Here is the main change:-

```
COLLECTION collection_;    //<------ #1 
//changed from   .... COLLECTION* collection_;
```

**Disadvantage:-**

- Whole data-structure (e.g. `std::vector`) will be value-copied - waste resource.
  (when use for `std::vector` directly)

### Workaround 2 (two versions of library, best?)

I will create 2 versions of the library - `AdapterValue` and `AdapterPointer`.
I have to create related classes (`Widget`,`AdapterIterator`,etc.) as well.

- `AdapterValue`   - **by value**.     (designed for `utilityAdapter()`)
- `AdapterPointer` - **by pointer**.   (designed for `std::vector`)

**Disadvantage:-**

- Duplicate code a lot     = low maintainability
- Users (coders) have to be very conscious about which one to pick = low robustness

### Workaround 3 (detect type)

I may use template specialization that do this :-

```
If( COLLECTION is an "CollectAdapter" ){ by value }  
Else{ by pointer }
```

**Disadvantage:-**

- Not cooperate well between many adapter classes.
  They have to recognize each other : **recognized** = should cache **by value**.

*Sorry for very long post.*

Comment: Without looking at your code, Boost Range adaptors all share a common pitfall with dangling references when adaptors are stored (and therefore used [after the end of the enclosing full-expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime)). I've burned myself so often that I have taken to avoid range adaptors except for cases where non-adaptor code is absolutely unwieldy

Comment: @sehe That is very useful. Thank.

Comment: Here's a reference case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40479397/getting-unexpected-result-when-compiling-with-clang-optimization/40482926#40482926, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36365241/how-do-i-create-a-const-boostiterator-range/36370974#36370974,

Comment: It is good to know that I aim for something which could be better than boost, even though it might be impractical or very hard.  :)

Comment: I'd suggest to look at Niebler's Range-V3 proposal (with the public implementation https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3)

Comment: @sehe wow, that is a large page with ton of information and link, hmm ... I think I have to dig it ... thank.

Comment: Please go easy on the minor edits. 28 is a little excessive, and most of those were extremely minor.

Comment: @Ed Cottrell  Thank for your generousness.  I am (too) nervous about any error / imperfection, because I am not good at English.   I believed my grammar error = disrespect readers.  I will take your advice, thank.  :)

Comment: "always by value" has another (even bigger) disadvantage: Imagine you want to modify the originally passed container - you won't ever be able to...

Answer (score 1):

I personally would go with template specialisation – however, not specialise the original template, but a nested class instead:

```
template<typename Collection, typename Adapter>
class CollectAdapter
{
    template<typename C>
    class ObjectKeeper // find some better name yourself...
    {
        C* object;
    public:
        C* operator*() { return object; };
        C* operator->() { return object; };
    };
    template<typename C, typename A>
    class ObjectKeeper <CollectAdapter<C, A>>
    {
        CollectAdapter<C, A> object;
    public:
        CollectAdapter<C, A>* operator*() { return &object; };
        CollectAdapter<C, A>* operator->() { return &object; };
    };

    ObjectKeeper<Collection> keeper;

    // now use *keeper or keeper-> wherever needed
};
```

The outer class then covers both cases by just always using pointers while the nested class hides the differences away.

Sure, incomplete (you yet need to add appropriate constructors, for instance, both to outer and inner class), but it should give you the idea...

You might even allow the user to select if she/he *wants* to copy:

```
template<typename Collection, typename Adapter, bool IsAlwaysCopy = false>
class CollectAdapter
{
    template<typename C, bool IsCopy>
    class ObjectWrapper // find some better name yourself...
    {
        C* object;
    public:
        C* operator*() { return object; };
        C* operator->() { return object; };
    };
    template<typename C>
    class ObjectWrapper<C, true>
    {
        C object;
    public:
        C* operator*() { return &object; };
        C* operator->() { return &object; };
    };

    // avoiding code duplication...
    template<typename C, bool IsCopy>
    class ObjectKeeper : public ObjectWrapper<C, IsCopy>
    { };
    template<typename C, typename A, bool IsCopy>
    class ObjectKeeper <CollectAdapter<C, A>, IsCopy>
        : public ObjectWrapper<CollectAdapter<C, A>, true>
    { };

    ObjectKeeper<Collection> keeper;
};
```

Comment: It looks like your `ObjectWrapper` is very similar to `std::reference_wrapper`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper

I could see a version of this done by specializing on `std::reference_wrapper` so OP's code would be `auto adapter1=CollectAdapterWidget::createAdapter(std::ref(t), func1);` `auto adapter12=CollectAdapterWidget::createAdapter(adapter1,func2);`. That would require by-reference (the typical case) to use `std::ref`. Perhaps it could be flipped so ref is default, but value is optional? That would be more dangerous.

Comment: Along those lines, it would be possible (but more dangerous) to have a version that takes the first argument by `const T&` which stores a reference and one that takes a `T&&` which stores it. Then `createAdapter(createAdapter(t, func1), func2)` would own the inner adapter but the inner adapter would just have a reference to t. I like the `&&` part of that, but not the implicit reference. You could not have a `const T&` creator and just allow `const std::reference_wrapper<const T>&`, `std::reference_wrapper<const T>&&`, and `T&&`. That seems reasonably safe...

Comment: ...in that `createAdapter(createAdapter(t, func1), func2)` wouldn't compile, but `createAdapter(createAdapter(std::ref(t), func1), func2)` would do what you'd expect. And `createAdapter(createAdapter(std::move(t), func1), func2)` would work.

Answer (score 1):

In my [`indexed_view`](https://github.com/anthonywilliams/indexed_view) I store the value of the collection if it is an rvalue, and store a reference if it is an lvalue. You could do the same here: overload your `operator|` for both rvalues and lvalues.

```
template<typename Collection,typename Filter>
auto operator|(Collection&& collection,Filter filter){
   return create_adapter_for_rvalue_collection(collection,filter);
}
template<typename Collection,typename Filter>
auto operator|(Collection const& collection,Filter filter){
   return create_adapter_for_const_lvalue_collection(collection,filter);
}
template<typename Collection,typename Filter>
auto operator|(Collection & collection,Filter filter){
   return create_adapter_for_non_const_lvalue_collection(collection,filter);
}
```